# Mysql table design and implementation

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table that i want to create in my database:

ID--Name--Major1--Univ1--Major2--Univ2--Major3-Univ3

The problem is, maybe the user did 9 majors. What i'm going to do create a table of 18 columns of major and univ... So is there a dynamic technique followed for this type of situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make  3 tables

**Primary tables**

```
Universities
id | name

Majors
id | name

students
id | name
```

**bridge_table**

```
student_major
students_id|university_id|major_id
```

Comment: normalize your db as much as you can.. this will make your easy

Answer (score 0):

You use two tables. :)

One table is the student table.
One table is the university / major table with a link to the student_id from the other table. Then a student can get unlimited majors. ;)

Comment: any links for use of this method, because the unlimited part confused me

Comment: To further normalize the data you can use 3 tables. One that contains the Student Information One that contains the unique majors and a third that has the primary key of the student and the major and relates the two.